# Constructor method of subclass for a superclass type object?

Tags: java, class, date, inheritance, constructor

I have seen constructer method of subclass being used for a variable with superclass type. For example:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Is `formatter` a `DateFormat` type object or a `SimpleDateFormat` type? Since the class `SimpleDateFormat` inherit from `DateFormat`, it probably has more methods than its superclass. Can the instance `formatter` call these functions only exist in `SimpleDateFormat` but not `DateFormat`? Are `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` interchangeable in this case? such as:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new DateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime type of `formatter` is determined by the constructor used to instantiate it, and its compile-time type is the one you used in the declaration. You cannot call a method on formatter that would exist on its actual runtime type and not on its declaration type, unless you use a cast to resolve the method call.

By the way, you could have answered your own questions by simple experiments :

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
        public void testSub() {
            System.out.println("Test sub");
        }

        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("Override test");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass sc = new SuperClass();
        sc.test();                      // prints Test
        sc = new SubClass();
        sc.test();                      // prints Override test
        sc.testSub();                   // does not compile
        ((SubClass) sc).testSub();      // prints Test sub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of a Java instance is determined by the constructor used for creating it, and cannot be changed.

The methods that may be invoked on an instance, depend on the type of the variable used to reference it. Therefore, you may invoke different sets of methods over the same instance, depending on the type of the variable you use to reference it.

The type of the variable used to reference an instance ONLY may be:

- The same type of the referenced instance
- A superclass of the type of the referenced instance
- An interface implemented by the type of the reference instance.

The higher in the class hierarchy that is the variable, the more general (and therefore, reusable) is the code that uses it. As a rule of design, you should use Interfaces as variable (and specially parameter) types.

Suggest you to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: so it is essentially the same as doing `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`? What is point of declare with "DateFormat" with constructor of its subclass?

Comment: @nasreddin It's exactly the same; and there is no benefit to declare it as a `DateFormat` first

Answer (score 0):

`formatter` is of both types, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. As soon as you call the constructor for `SimpleDateFormat`, it also calls the constructor for `DateFormat` - but it is only one Object.

To access methods from `SimpleDateFormat`, you can cast it:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) formatter;
```

This only works as long as `formatter` is of type `SimpleDateFormat` or any subclass of it. The following line will produce an compile error:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
```

---

By the way, I would just declare `formatter` as a `SimpleDateFormat` from the beginning. You have no benefit from declaring it as a `DateFormat` and than cast it - this is a waste of your CPU.